# How to convert 09:20:05 time format in hour using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where a column contains time value and i want to convert it into hour and also compare it with 0.

For Ex:
Time = [02:20:10,01:10:05,03:20:14,04:34:09,05:05:34,06:40:20]
And Want:

Time = [02,01,03,04,05,06] in int format....

Comment: df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_column']).dt.hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), then perform integer division by 3600 seconds with [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.floordiv.html)

If you have a column/Series:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).dt.total_seconds().floordiv(3600).astype(int)
```

output:

```
0    2
1    1
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

From a python list:

```
Time = ['02:20:10','01:10:05','03:20:14','04:34:09','05:05:34','06:40:20']

pd.to_timedelta(Time).total_seconds()//3600
```

output: `Float64Index([2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], dtype='float64')`

*NB. This solution works for any number of hours (e.g., `'34:12:56'`). If you are sure that your time cannot exceed '23:59:59', you could also use `pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.hour`.*